# PDO disconnect and PHP variable reference

Tags: php, pdo, php-5.2

I'm new to PHP high level. But not new to programming.

We have a software (in dismission but still active) that is killing our DB.

Inside is used PDO the problem after a lot of spent time is PDO disconnection mode and the useof PDO inside a wrap class.

```
public function connect() {
    if(!$this->connected){
        $col = 'mysql:host='
                .$this->parametri->getHOST()
                .';'
                .'dbname='
                .$this->parametri->getDB()
                .';'
                .'charset=utf8';

        try {
            // connessione tramite creazione di un oggetto PDO
            $db = new PDO($col , $this->parametri->getDBUSER(), 
                                 $this->parametri->getPASS());
            $this->pdoconn=$db;
            $this->connected=TRUE;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->connected=FALSE;
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return  $this->pdoconn;
}

public function getPDO(){
        if ($this->connected){
            return $this->pdoconn;
        }else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

public function disconnect() {
        $this->pdoconn=null;
        $this->connected=FALSE;
    }
```

Reading PDO documentation and comments on the official site the connection is freed when  $this->pdoconn=null;
but it has passed via getPDO().

According to [this article](https://derickrethans.nl/talks/phparch-php-variables-article.pdf) and [this dissertion](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-do-not-use-php-references.html), somewhere there could be a variable pointing to connection so the connection is never freed; the class think the connection is freed and when request create a new connection losing the last one to the user of the class.

So the idea is to pass back the connection tu null also this or there is another way to protect pdoconn and force to be null.

```
public function disconnect(&$var) {
     $var=null;
     $this->pdoconn=null;
     $this->connected=FALSE;
}
```

Another way is to build anothe wrap class that never expose the pdo conn and force to execute the query inside it to manage also the disconnection.

Comment: What about having a static variable (singleton) that you assign the connection to. Almost what you have now but static so it reuses the same connection because static will persist without creating new connections.

Comment: Both solutions are very interesting I don't know which one to vote

Comment: Try one out and see if your load on the database resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try making the connection and/or class a `singleton`, it should then persist the database connection and every time you go to use it, it will be the same connection. If you do it this way, you don't have to focus on closing the connection every time you use it because there is only one connection throughout the page. Here is a simple example:

```
class MyClass
    {
        // You can make the class itself persist to save on resources
        private static $obj;
        // You can save the connection specifically to reuse it
        private static $singleton;
        // Return itself to static var
        public function __construct()
            {
                if(!empty(self::$obj)) {
                    echo 'OLD OBJ<br />';
                    return self::$obj;
                }
                echo 'NEW OBJ<br />';
                self::$obj = $this;
                return self::$obj;
            }
        // Return connection if already set
        public function connect($username = "username",$password = "password",$host = "host",$database = "dbname")
            {
                if(!empty(self::$singleton)) {
                    echo 'OLD CONN<br />';
                    return self::$singleton;
                }

                try {
                     self::$singleton = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database.';charset=utf8',$username,$password);
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    die('connection failed');
                }
                echo 'NEW CONN<br />';
                return  self::$singleton;
            }
    }
```

**Examples of use:**

```
    // Creates first PDO connection
    $database = new MyClass();
    $con1 = $database->connect();

    function getConnection()
        {   
            // Creates first connection
            $database = new MyClass();
            return $database->connect();
        }

    // Won't create a new instance, but rather use the same.
    $con2 = getConnection();
```

**Will write:**

```
NEW OBJ
NEW CONN
OLD OBJ
OLD CONN
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've implemented a singleton DB instance to keep a persistent DB connection:

```
class DB implements IConnectInfo {
    public static function factory() {
        if( self::$_instance === null ) {
            self::$_instance = new DB( 'HOST', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE' );
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    protected function __construct( $host, $username, $password, $database ) {
        try {
            $this->_link = new PDO( "mysql:host={$host};dbname={$database}", $username, $password, array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8" ) );
            $this->_link->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $this->_link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->_link = null;
            die( "ERROR: Could not connect to the database" );
        }
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        if ( $this->_hasActiveTransaction ) {
            $this->commit();
        }
    }

    final private function __clone() {
    }

    public function &link() {
        return $this->_link;
    }

    public function beginTransaction() {
        if ( $this->_hasActiveTransaction == false ) {
            try {
                $this->_link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->_link->beginTransaction();
                $this->_hasActiveTransaction = true;
                return true;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                error_log($e);
                die();
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function rollBack() {
        if( !$this->beginTransaction() ) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            $this->_link->rollBack();
            $this->_hasActiveTransaction = false;
            return true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function commit() {
        if( !$this->beginTransaction() ) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            $this->_link->commit();
            $this->_hasActiveTransaction = false;
            return true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->rollBack();
            return false;
        }

    }

    private $_hasActiveTransaction = false;
    private $_result = null;
    private $_link = null;
    static private $_instance = null;
}
```

And then I'm using it like this:

```
$DB = DB::factory();
$query = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
$stmt = $DB->link()->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute();
while( $myTableObj = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ) {
     echo $myTableObj->myField
}
```